# Boot to terminal, startx doesn't work

Tags: 12.04

After I updated the drivers for my video card and restarted, Ubuntu booted the terminal instead of the graphical interface. `startx` and `sudo startx` doesn't work.

`xorg --configure` doesn't work either and `sudo Xorg --configure` does the same.

What now?

Version: 12.04 LTS 64-bit
Video card: ATI radeon 5000 series

Comment: * Starting LightDM Display Manager            [fail]

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
sudo start lightdm
```

It does exactly the same as

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

There are also:

```
sudo stop lightdm
sudo restart lightdm
```

If you have other login managers replace lightdm with what you have - so if you use GNOME (and selected the GNOME login manager) it is

```
sudo start gdm
```

If you have KDE (and selected the KDE login manager) it is

```
sudo start kdm
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

This will start your LightDM display manager.